# How do I add an animation delay between each iteration

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have applied an iteration of 'infinite' to make the code repeat forever, however there is no delay, how can I add a delay between each repeat?

```css
.type {
  width: max-content;

}
.type h1{
    animation: typing 3s steps(31) infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0%{
        width: 0%;
    }
    100%{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="type">
    <h1>Hobbies, Goals, and Aspirations</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a keyframe at **50%** in your *@keyframes* rule and make it `width:100%`, then increase your animations *duration* to double that of its current duration. That way, if it is 6 seconds, then you will have a 3 second pause before the infinite loop starts at 0% again.

```css
.type {
  width: max-content;

}
.type h1{
    animation: typing 6s steps(31) infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    width: 0;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0%{
        width: 0%;
    }
    50%, 100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="type">
    <h1>Hobbies, Goals, and Aspirations</h1>
</div>
```